# Including a jar in maven local repository

Tags: pom.xml

I want to include a jar in my local repository(google-api-java-client 1.6.0-beta). To include that we need to write in the pom.xml, but while I try to include it , its not getting included in local Repository. Below is the pom.xml of my project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<!-- The Basics -->
<groupId>com.google.tryPredictionJava</groupId>
<artifactId>gae-java</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>try-prediction-java</name>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>maven-gae-plugin-repo</id>
        <name>maven-gae-plugin repository</name>
        <url>http://maven-gae-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/repository</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>google-api-services</id>
        <url>http://mavenrepo.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>maven-gae-plugin-repo</id>
        <name>maven-gae-plugin repository</name>
        <url>http://maven-gae-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/repository</url>
    </repository>

</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <!-- 8th Apr <dependency> <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId> <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId> 
        <version>1.13.2-beta</version> </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.1-beta</version>
    </dependency>




    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0-beta</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId> <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId> 
        <version>1.4.0-beta</version> </dependency> -->


    <!-- 8th Apr <dependency> <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId> <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId> 
        <version>1.13.1-beta</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId> 
        <artifactId>google-oauth-client-servlet</artifactId> <version>1.13.1-beta</version> 
        </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>com.google.api.client</groupId> <artifactId>google-api-client-http</artifactId> 
        <version>1.2.3-alpha</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId> 
        <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId> <version>1.13.2-beta</version> 
        </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId> <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId> 
        <version>1.13.0-beta</version> </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.1-beta</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-oauth-client-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.1-beta</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client-http</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3-alpha</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.1-beta</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.1-beta</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId> <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId> 
        <version>1.13.0-beta</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId> 
        <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId> <version>1.13.0-beta</version> 
        </dependency> -->



    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.1-beta</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>1.13.1-beta</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- -->
    <!-- Google App Engine meta-package -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.kindleit</groupId>
        <artifactId>gae-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>${gae.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
        <version>${datanucleus.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Java EE Servlet API. We need it to compile IndexServlet class. You can 
        probably remove it, if you don't explicitly use Servlets -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-servlet_2.5_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Make use of JSP tags. Remove, if you don't use JSPs -->
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- These dependencies are here just for enabling logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.24</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test scope -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- GAE libraries for local testing as described here: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/howto/unittesting.html -->


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
        <version>${gae.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
        <version>${gae.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId> <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId> 
        <version>1.4.1-beta</version> </dependency> -->

    <!-- 8th Apr <dependency> <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId> <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId> 
        <version>1.13.2-beta</version> </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.1-beta</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-prediction</artifactId>
        <version>v1.4-1.3.0-beta</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--<dependency> <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId> <artifactId>google-api-services-plus</artifactId> 
        <version>v1-rev22-1.8.0-beta</version> </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-plus</artifactId>
        <version>v1-rev62-1.14.1-beta</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdo2-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3-eb</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
                <artifactId>transaction-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>${gae.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-labs</artifactId>
        <version>${gae.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.1-beta</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.1-beta</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency> 8th Apr <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId> <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId> 
        <version>1.13.0-beta</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId> 
        <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId> <version>1.13.0-beta</version> 
        </dependency> -->
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.kindleit</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-gae-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <port>8080</port>
                <address>127.0.0.1</address>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-gae</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                        <goal>unpack</goal>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-gae</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <!-- This plug-in "enhances" your domain model objects (i.e. makes them 
            persistent for datanucleus) -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-datanucleus-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Make sure this path contains your persistent classes! -->
                <mappingIncludes>**/model/*.class</mappingIncludes>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <enhancerName>ASM</enhancerName>
                <api>JDO</api>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enhance</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                    <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
                    <version>${datanucleus.version}</version>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
                            <artifactId>transaction-api</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                    <artifactId>datanucleus-rdbms</artifactId>
                    <version>${datanucleus.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                    <artifactId>datanucleus-enhancer</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.4</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jdo2-api</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3-ec</version>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1-beta-1</version>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/appengine-web.xml</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- The actual maven-gae-plugin. Type "mvn gae:run" to run project, "mvn 
            gae:deploy" to upload to GAE. -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.kindleit</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-gae-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.kindleit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gae-runtime</artifactId>
                    <version>${gae.version}</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Upload application to the appspot automatically, during release:perform -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <goals>gae:deploy</goals>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Java compiler version -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<!-- Specify hard-coded project properties here -->
<properties>

    <!-- Sets the project's default encoding. http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/POM+Element+for+Source+File+Encoding -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <!-- This is just for "eclipse:eclipse" goal to always attempt downloading 
        sources -->
    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>

    <!-- Specify AppEngine version for your project. It should match SDK version 
        pointed to by ${gae.home} property (Typically, one used by your Eclipse plug-in) 
        <gae.version>1.6.1</gae.version> -->
    <gae.version>1.6.3</gae.version>

    <!-- Upload to http://test.latest.<applicationName>.appspot.com by default -->
    <gae.application.version>test</gae.application.version>

    <datanucleus.version>1.1.5</datanucleus.version>
</properties>

<profiles>
    <!-- We can configure our integration server to activate this profile and 
        perform gae:deploy, thus uploading latest snapshot to the http://1.latest.<applicationName>.appspot.com 
        automatically -->
    <profile>
        <id>integration-build</id>
        <properties>
            <gae.application.version>stage</gae.application.version>
        </properties>
    </profile>

    <!-- This profile will activate automatically during release and upload 
        application to the http://2.latest.<applicationName>.appspot.com (We might 
        want to set the 2nd version as our applications Default version to be accessible 
        at http://<applicationName>.appspot.com) -->
    <profile>
        <id>release-build</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>performRelease</name>
                <value>true</value>
            </property>
        </activation>

        <properties>
            <!-- During release, set application version in appengine-web.xml to 
                2 -->
            <gae.application.version>release</gae.application.version>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: You want to install jar in local repository?

Answer (score 1):

Latest version in central repo is 1.4.1-beta

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1-beta</version>
</dependency>
```

Download newest JAR and install in local repository

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=google-api-client.jar -DgroupId=com.google.api.client \
    -DartifactId=google-api-client -Dversion=1.6.0-beta -Dpackaging=jar
```